# Qlikview - barchart

Tags: bar-chart, qlikview

I want to create bar chart but i don't now how to set dimension and expressions. I have got this table

[image]

and I need to create a bar chart to look like this:

[image]
I need to have the average result(avgREsult column) on x-axis green color and expressions count(Item) and around green bar to get blue bars that represents pros column and expressions count(item).

Any idea?

Comment: Try including more information on what you have already tried.

Comment: i am new in qlikview, i add avgResult and proc like dimension and expressions count(item) but it's not ok

Comment: I feel that your question should be easy to address, but it is hard to help you with so confusing info. Try extending your question: better explanation, what do you have so far,  do you get an error? do you get wrong values?